# Convert Json to XML in Java with Staxon

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm trying to convert Json to XML

```
public static String jsonToXML1(String source) {
    String xmlString = null;

    try {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        JsonXMLConfig config = new JsonXMLConfigBuilder().virtualRoot("root").autoPrimitive(false).autoArray(true).multiplePI(true).build();
        XMLStreamReader streamReader = new JsonXMLInputFactory(config).createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
        Source source1 = new StAXSource(streamReader);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);

        tf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
        tf.newTransformer().transform(source1, new StreamResult(stringWriter));

        xmlString = stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    return xmlString;
}

System.out.println(jsonToXML1("[{\"ID\":\"a\"},{\"ID\":\"b\"}]"));
```

But when I call it with `[{"ID":"a"},{"ID":"b"}]`, I get `<root><ID>a</ID></root>` instead of

```
<root><element><ID>a</ID></element><element><ID>b</ID></element></root>
```

or

```
<root><ID>a</ID><ID>b</ID></root>
```

This seem to work fine if the object does not contain an array.
In the case of an array, jut the first element is converted.
Can you point me out how I can convert all the array elements?

Comment: You've tagged this Saxon, and mentioned Saxon in the question, but I see no use of Saxon in your code (it's explicitly invoking Xalan). So I'm confused. It actually seems to be a question about some JsonXMLConfig library.

Comment: I see that JsonXMLConfig is in the "staxon" product which has absolutely no connection to saxon other than having (deliberately?) chosen a confusingly similar name.

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for correcting it. I was thinking that was the Saxon library.

Comment: Thanks @Valentyn Kolesnikov, unfortunately I'm trying to avoid adding new dependencies

Comment: @lonut It is open source library. You may copy source codes to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library has static method `U.jsonToXml(json)`. I am the maintainer of the project.

```
U.jsonToXml("[{\"ID\":\"a\"},{\"ID\":\"b\"}]");

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <element>
    <ID>a</ID>
  </element>
  <element>
    <ID>b</ID>
  </element>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below example works for json to xml convertion including xml attributes.

INPUT JSON: `{"Header":{"From":{"Credential":[{"@domain":"AribaNetworkUserId","@type":"marketplace","Identity":"bigadmin@marketplace.org"},{"@domain":"AribaNetworkUserId","@type":"marketplace","Identity":"bigadmin@marketplace.org"}]},"To":{"Credential":[{"@domain":"AribaNetworkUserId","@type":"marketplace","Identity":"bigadmin@marketplace.org"},{"@domain":"AribaNetworkUserId","@type":"marketplace","Identity":"bigadmin@marketplace.org"}]},"Sender":{"Credential":[{"@domain":"AribaNetworkUserId","Identity":"dchen@ariba.com","SharedSecret":"password"},{"@domain":"AribaNetworkUserId","Identity":"dchen@ariba.com","SharedSecret":"password"}],"UserAgent":"Ariba Network V1.1"}}}`

XML OUTPUT: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Header><From><Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId" type="marketplace"><Identity>bigadmin@marketplace.org</Identity></Credential><Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId" type="marketplace"><Identity>bigadmin@marketplace.org</Identity></Credential></From><To><Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId" type="marketplace"><Identity>bigadmin@marketplace.org</Identity></Credential><Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId" type="marketplace"><Identity>bigadmin@marketplace.org</Identity></Credential></To><Sender><Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId"><Identity>dchen@ariba.com</Identity><SharedSecret>password</SharedSecret></Credential><Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId"><Identity>dchen@ariba.com</Identity><SharedSecret>password</SharedSecret></Credential><UserAgent>Ariba Network V1.1</UserAgent></Sender></Header>`

SOURCE CODE:

```
import com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl;
import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLConfig;
import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLConfigBuilder;
import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLInputFactory;
import de.odysseus.staxon.json.JsonXMLOutputFactory;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class StaxonJsonXmlConverter implements JsonXmlConverter {

    public String jsonToXml(String json) throws ConverterException {

InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        JsonXMLConfig config = new JsonXMLConfigBuilder().multiplePI(isMultiplePI()).prettyPrint(false).build();
        try {
            /*
             * Create reader (JSON).
             */
            XMLEventReader reader = new JsonXMLInputFactory(config).createXMLEventReader(input, ServiceConstants.UTF_8);

            /*
             * Create writer (XML). I don't love using the internal XMLOutputFactoryImpl directly, but the
             * alternative is to use the VM option:
             * -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl'
             * which is basically just like instantiating it directly, right??
             */
            XMLEventWriter writer = new XMLOutputFactoryImpl().createXMLEventWriter(output, ServiceConstants.UTF_8);

            /*
             * Copy events from reader to writer.
             */
            writer.add(reader);

            /*
             * Close reader/writer.
             */
            reader.close();
            writer.close();

            return output.toString();

 }
}
```